# PopupWindow setAnimationStyle() не работает в android 2.3

Tags: android, анимация

Хочу анимировать popupWindow, но в 2.3 не работает код:

```
setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupAnimation);
```

Хотя в 4+ работает отлично!

Пробовал непосредственно на вьюху повешать анимацию:

```
popupView.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.enter));
```

Появляется как надо! Как заставить и исчезать popupWindow с анимацией?

```
  <style name="PopupAnimation" parent="android:Animation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/enter</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/exit</item>
    </style>
```

enter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

exit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />

</set>
```

Comment: покажите содержание R.style.PopupAnimation

Comment: а файлы с анимацией?

Comment: @Andreich добавил!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте прописать:

`@android:windowEnterAnimation` вместо `android:windowEnterAnimation` и `@android:windowExitAnimation` вместо `android:windowExitAnimation`.

[описание windowEnterAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowEnterAnimation)

Comment: Не помогло!